# How can I make this binary to float algorithm more efficient / shortened

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this algorithm takes in user binary input as xxxx.xxxx and then outputs decimal equivalent of it. Keeping the same format and style, how can I shorten / make it more efficient?

```
import math
binary = {"Input":input("Enter your binary value here in the format of x.x : ").split("."), "Int":0, "Float":0}
for k, v in enumerate(binary["Input"][0][::-1]):
    if int(v) == 1:
        binary["Int"]= binary["Int"] + (2**(k))
for k, v in enumerate(binary["Input"][1]):
    if int(v) == 1:
        binary["Float"] = binary["Float"]+ (1/math.pow(2,k+1))
print(binary["Float"]+binary["Int"])
```

Comment: for hex it would be trivial: `float.hex(1.3)`, `float.fromhex('0xa.bcdefp+0')`. maybe you can build on that.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, it would be better if you only did one pass over the string.

Currently, you do three passes: split, reverse (partially), and compute.

Also, don't do this `binary[...]` stuff, just use variables.

Here is an implementation that does exactly one pass:

```
def bin2float(s):
    result = exp = 0
    for k in s:
        if k == ".":
            exp = 1
            continue
        result *= 2
        exp *= 2
        if k == '1':
            result += 1
    exp = max(exp, 1)
    return result / exp

print(bin2float('Enter your binary value here in the format of x.x :')
```

If you're only after shortening, use individual variables, and use `+=`, also don't use `int(v) == '1'`, but `v == '1'`, and use `math.pow(2, -k-1)` instead of `(1/math.pow(2,k+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

a version using `hex` instead of doing the calculation in a loop (not tested!):

```
def bin_str_to_hex_str(bin_str):
    '''
    extend the binary number after the '.' such that its length is a multiple
    of 8; convert to hex.
    '''
    a, b = bin_str.split('.')
    while len(b)%8 != 0:
        b += '0'
    hex_str = '{}.{}p+0'.format(hex(int(a,2)), hex(int(b,2))[2:])
    return hex_str

def bin_str_to_float(bin_str):
    hex_str =  bin_str_to_hex_str(bin_str)
    return float.fromhex(hex_str)

print(bin_str_to_float('010010010.010010101'))  # -> 146.291015625
```

admittedly this converts twice (once for the hex string, then the hex string itself) which is not very nice... there is probably a cleverer way to assemble the parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bin2Dec(bin_value):
    bin_value = '0' + bin_value #to avoid the input format case, like '.11'
    parts = bin_value.split(".")
    integer_part = int(parts[0],2)
    fraction_part = 0
    if len(parts) == 2:
        fraction_part = sum([int(val) * (10 ** (-id)) for id, val in enumerate(parts[1],start = 1)])
    return integer_part + fraction_part
```

the integer part can be done by built-in function [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import pow as pow
import timeit

def bin2float(bin_str):
  index = bin_str.index('.')
  high = bin_str[:index]
  low = bin_str[index+1:]

  high_f = int(high,2)
  low_f = int(low,2)/pow(2,len(low))

  return high_f+low_f

def b2f(bin):
  int_s,float_s =bin.split(".")
  int_v = 0
  float_v =0
  for k, v in enumerate(int_s[::-1]):
    if int(v) == 1:
        int_v += (2**(k))
  for k, v in enumerate(float_s):
    if int(v) == 1:
        float_v += (1/pow(2,k+1))
  return int_v+float_v


if __name__ == "__main__":
  bin ='010010010.010010101'
  stmt1 = "bin2float('{0}')".format(bin)
  stmt2= "b2f('{0}')".format(bin)
  print(timeit.timeit(stmt1,"from bin2float import bin2float",number =10000 ))
  print(timeit.timeit(stmt2,"from bin2float import b2f",number =10000 ))
```

test result:

```
0.015675368406093453
0.08317904950635754
```

in fact, your way to handle the float part is just equal to

```
int(low,2)/pow(2,len(low))
```

which handles the part as a whole.